# Ear pads for Grado SR225 headphones

Tags: equipment, headphones

I have both the Grado SR2225 headphones, and the Sennheiser Urbanite XL. I like the ear pads on the Sennheiser much better. The Sennheiser is covered with some sort of soft fabric, while the Grados are with foam.

Can you suggest a compatible replacement of similar quality to the Sennheisers, for my Grados?